# Run roles according to host from Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have to use two playbooks as my host are changing for each role. Is there any workaround so that I can get this done in single playbook??

Playbook-1:

```
- name: Install & configure SSH on servers
  gather_facts: True
  sudo: yes
  hosts: zookeeper
  roles:
  - { role: discover-zookeeper,         tags: ['discover-zookeeper']}
```

Playbook-2:

```
- name: Install & configure SSH on servers
  gather_facts: True
  sudo: yes
  hosts: kafka
  roles:
  - { role: discover-kafka,             tags: ['discover-kafka']}
```

I have tried this approach, but it seems that it's not how Ansible works..

playbook.yml:

```
- name: Install & configure SSH on servers
  gather_facts: True
  sudo: yes
  roles:
  - { role: discover-zookeeper,         tags: ['discover-zookeeper'],   hosts: zookeeper}
  - { role: discover-kafka,             tags: ['discover-kafka'],   hosts: kafka}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I see it correctly, you are talking about two plays, NOT two playbooks. Because a playbook is, as fas as I understand your question, exactly what you are looking for. As an example:

```
- hosts: hostA
  roles:
    - roleA
    - roleB
- hosts: hostB
  roles:
    - roleC
    - roleD
```

(comment: please use "(cmd/ctrl) + k" to format in better readable code-style)

Comment: Thakns! This is what I needed!!